# RestKit giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios5, restkit

I've been trying to get RestKit to work on my app but am unsuccessful.  I have an ARC enabled app, and I installed it using https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x.  I've been reading articles on StackOverflow saying I need a singleton class or something.  I went back to the basics and tried to follow the example at: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Tutorial-%3A-Introduction-to-RestKit.

In my AppDelegate, I have:

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://restkit.org"];
   NSLog(@"I am your RKClient singleton: %@", [RKClient sharedClient]);
```

In my other class, I have:

```
    - (void) sendRequests {
    [[RKClient sharedClient] get: @"/foo.xml" delegate:self];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"RestKit" forKey:@"Sender"];
    [ [RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/other.json" params:params delegate:self];

    // DELETE a remote resource from the server
    [ [RKClient sharedClient] delete:@"/missing_resource.txt" delegate:self];

}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {  
    if ([request isGET]) {
        // Handling GET /foo.xml

        if ([response isOK]) {
            // Success! Let's take a look at the data
            NSLog(@"Retrieved XML: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        }

    } else if ([request isPOST]) {

        // Handling POST /other.json        
        if ([response isJSON]) {
            NSLog(@"Got a JSON response back from our POST!");
        }

    } else if ([request isDELETE]) {

        // Handling DELETE /missing_resource.txt
        if ([response isNotFound]) {
            NSLog(@"The resource path '%@' was not found.", [request resourcePath]);
        }
    }
}

- (void) requestWillPrepareForSend:(RKRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"request: %@",request);
}
```

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code -1, address = 0x766c6550) error, and the line it's pointing to is:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWillPrepareForSend:)]) {
```

By the way, I am calling getRequest by doing the following:

```
RestHandler *myRestHandler = [[RestHandler alloc] init];
[myRestHandler sendRequests];
```

and RestHandler does have .

Can anyone provide me with some insight here?  I read a bunch of articles on StackOverflow but I went back to the basics and still couldn't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `self.delegate` just before the error? (NSLog)

Comment: NSLog(@"self.delegate is: %@",self.delegate);  I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.. I thought

[[RKClient sharedClient] get: @"/foo.xml" delegate:self];

would set the delegate

Comment: I created a static class, and now I am seeing: 

2012-06-01 11:29:11.870 BareTerminalApp[147:707] request: <RKRequest: 0xc663610>
2012-06-01 11:29:11.887 BareTerminalApp[147:707] request: <RKRequest: 0xc66be00>
2012-06-01 11:29:11.893 BareTerminalApp[147:707] request: <RKRequest: 0xc66c600>
2012-06-01 11:29:12.311 BareTerminalApp[147:707] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:676 Status Code: 404
2012-06-01 11:29:12.319 BareTerminalApp[147:707] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:676 Status Code: 404
2012-06-01 11:29:12.322 BareTerminalApp[147:707] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:676 Status Code: 404

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use that code if you do not use a local variable for the request. Put RestHandler object on the AppDelegate instance variables, and do something like:

```
@interface RSAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate> {
    RestHandler *myRestHandler;
}
```

And in the applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
myRestHandler = [[RestHandler alloc] init];
[myRestHandler sendRequests];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the property of `myRestHandler` as strong. The object is loosing its memory before the url request being formed by `Restkit`.